# What's the number to the right of the orange dot?

Tags: support

That is the one up next to my username at the top of the page. The far right number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the number of badges of that color that you've earned; hover over it for more details. (The "orange" one is meant to be bronze.)

Comment: Ah! I never hovered over it long enough. ;)